# How to find the exact different value from two string?

Tags: java, android

I have two different strings, `result` and `result1`. `result` is a new value obtained from a website content without changing anything in website and it is stored in SQLite and later the website content will be changed and obtain the content and it will be saved in `result1`. I want to compare these two string `result` and `result1` and find out which content is added newly. I want to show the new added content. Here I mentioned the code to check the `result` and `result1` values.

```
String[] items = result1.split(">");
for (String item : items)
{
    Log.i("Result1", item);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input for "result" & "result1"?  Along with expected results of comparison?

Comment: its like a website content based on some website...

Answer (score 1):

This is a clear case of the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Check it out and google will provide you with lots of implementations ;)

Comment: Does that tell you which is different? As far as I know it only tells you, that something is different.

Comment: It tells you how different two strings are. So if the difference > 0, you know it's different. And what do you mean by 'which is different'? Can you compare an apple to an orange and say: 'the orange is different from the apple' without implying the apple is also different from the orange? If string A and B are different, then both are different.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to tell the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344721/extract-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-java

Comment: Ahh now I understand your question, that way you know what the difference is! But those operations are quite compilation-time heavy. So if you only need to know IF there is a difference, use levenshtein, otherwise use google's tools.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between 2 String can be found using

```
String strDiffChop(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length > s2.length) {
        return s1.substring(s2.length - 1);
    } else if (s2.length > s1.length) {
        return s2.substring(s1.length - 1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't own this , but have tried .

[Find difference between two Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089967/find-difference-between-two-strings)[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089967/find-difference-between-two-strings)

Comment: i want to find exact content @Prabhuraj