# How to remove substring from a String?

Tags: java, string, function, replace, substring

I would like to share my code with you to help me improve.

I need to write a function that returns a `String` consisting of `string1` minus all the characters of `string2`.

Here is what I tried, unfortunately it doesn't work that well:

```java
public static String remove(String str1, String str2) {
    String empty = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) { // hello ll
        for (int j = 0; j < str1.length(); j++) {
            if (str2.charAt(i) != str1.charAt(j)) {
                empty = empty + str1.charAt(j);

            }
        }
    }
    return empty;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find difference between two Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089967/find-difference-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` to check if a character does not exist in the second `String`. Currently, you are not checking all the characters of the second `String` before determining whether or not the current character should be added. Additionally, it is better to use a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating inside a loop.

```java
public static String remove(String str1, String str2) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        if (str2.indexOf(str1.charAt(i)) == -1) {
            sb.append(str1.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```java
public static String remove(String str1, String str2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++)
        str1 = str1.replace(str2.charAt(i) + "", "");
    return str1;
}
```

From the string 1 you replace all the character from string 2 by "".

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, for each character in the first strings, you iterate over the characters in the second string, and append the character to the result if the two differ. This isn't the behavior that's expected - you need to append the character only if it differs from **all** the characters in the second string.

Keeping the format of the method you shared as much as possible, you'd want to do something like this:

```java
public static String remove(String str1, String str2) {
    String empty = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < str1.length() && !found; j++) {
            if (str2.charAt(i) == str1.charAt(j)) {
                found  = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            empty += str1.charAt(i)
    }
    return empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*`String` consisting of `string1` minus all the characters of `string2`*:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(remove("hello", "ll")); // heo
    System.out.println(remove("hello", "eo")); // hll
    System.out.println(remove("hello", "lo")); // he
}
```

```java
public static String remove(String str1, String str2) {
    return str1.codePoints()
            .filter(ch -> !str2.contains(Character.toString(ch)))
            .mapToObj(Character::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```